# Usefulness of fork() besides executing foreign programs

Tags: c++, multithreading

The tutorials, manuals and other resources I read about `fork()` usually only contain examples which could be solved much better with threads. They just communicate, do some very basic tasks, and communicate again to share or display the results. I have the feeling that unless your intention is starting a foreign program, (by having the father continuing and the child starting that foreign program), threads are always easier to handle, more flexible, and safer than forks.

Is there any other area of application when a `fork()` would be superior to just using threads? Except for a virus, that is.

Comment: On some/many OSs, processes are _cheaper_ than threads.

Comment: Actually threads often are way more complicated to use than processes for tasks that do not need much of the data to be shared.

Comment: @Matteo: It depends. I find for example Qt's threads to be many times easier to use than having a program to communicate with copies of itself.

Comment: @ildjarn - cheaper?  Since a process must have at least one thread to provide it with execution, how is that possible?

Comment: @Martin : I can't say I know the details, but I believe it has to due with the scheduler and how context switches are made between separate processes vs. separate threads within the same process. You'd have to ask a kernel dev for a real explanation (or, you know, a search engine).

Comment: @ildjarn: cheaper? What if you program uses hundreds of megabytes of memory before forking, but you only need much less in your child process/thread?

Comment: @vsz: the hundred of megabytes of memory are kept shared in copy-on-write behind the scenes by any virtual memory manager.

Comment: @vsz: The memory consumption issue is complicated by the use of copy-on-write semantics...the child will only get an *actual* copy of pages it alters.

Comment: `fork()` predates the various thread mechanisms by at least a decade. So, if you need portability to V7 UNIX, `fork()` is a much better choice.

Comment: `fork` can be used to daemonize your process while keeping the monitor process alive.

Comment: One typical example would be a web server (e.g., Apache). If a process crashes, it's easy to restart cleanly -- not so with threads. Using separate processes limits the damage you can get from a single process crashing.

Comment: Yep. I'll almost always opt for a multiprocess approach over a multithreaded one becuase of the isolation levels involved (as discussed above.)  Plus the code is so much simpler.

Comment: Windows doesn't have `fork`, so it's obviously not mandatory. Also many modern GUI environments (Cocoa, Gnome) don't support a lone `fork` without `exec`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fork()` as a simple way to generate a snapshot from an application without stopping the original application.

Since the OS maps the process's virtual memory as copy on write, you don't really pay any cost except for data that has changed (plus OS overhead).

**Edit:** Added answers from comments for the sake of later viewers.

One typical example would be a web server (e.g., Apache). If a process crashes, it's easy to restart cleanly -- not so with threads. Using separate processes limits the damage you can get from a single process crashing. – Jerry Coffin

`fork()` predates the various thread mechanisms by at least a decade. So, if you need portability to V7 UNIX, `fork()` is a much better choice. – Robᵩ

`fork()` can be used to daemonize your process while keeping the monitor process alive. – Mark B

Comment: What use does this have besides debugging? A very lengthy self-diagnostic function which takes a lot of time and should not keep the program hanging?

Comment: @vsz, snapshots aren't just for debugging. I use them all the time so that I can cache the results of a 9 hour process.